# How can I modify the Lyra camera to make a Top Down game in UE5?

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine5

I'm trying to make a Battlerite like game. Lyra comes with CM_ArenaFramingCamera which produces a fixed camera that doesn't track the player. I don't really understand how this is achieved, and I'm not sure how I could modify it to follow the player. Where would something like that happen and how would it play into the Ability system?

I've also tried looking at the CM_ThirdPerson camera to modify it to function as a top down camera. I understand how to change the curves to position the camera, but there's a lot of weird behavior associated with this and I'm unclear of how to fix the rotation.

I'd appreciate anybody that has a deep dive on using the Lyra system to modify and create custom cameras!

Answer (score 0):

To get the same effect as the SpringArmComponent what I basically dis was to create a new class inheriting from ULyraCameraMode and copy paste all the methods from SpringArmComponent. The tick component I replaced it with the method ULyraCameraMode::UpdateView. The most important modification you have to do is inside the method UpdateDesiredArmLocation(), here at very end of all the calculations just set.

```
View.Location = ResultLoc;
View.Rotation = DesiredRot;
```